# Plotting UK regions in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to plot regions within UK to a map in rstudio but the coordinates I have are for the town level. Does anyone know where/how I can plot my data at regional level instead of town level in rstudio?

Thanks.

Comment: use this to identify the cooordicnates-http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=&country=GB

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

What kind of data do you want to plot in these regions/towns?

If you are simply looking for a map of UK regions (county, local authority, country, etc.) then I would recommend taking a look at [GADM maps & data](https://gadm.org/). You can choose the level of detail you want from these maps by specifying levels, which I think vary from 1 to 3 for UK. By the way, the country code for UK is `GBR`

Below is an example of how you can plot a UK map using leaflet package with level 2 detail, which I think might be what you are looking for.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)  
# download uk data level 2 from GADM  
uk <- getData('GADM', country='GBR', level = 2)  

library(leaflet)
# creating a colour palette that provides a diff colour for regions
# in different country i.e., Scotland, Ireland, Wales, etc.  
pal <- colorFactor("Reds", uk$ID_2)
leaflet(uk) %>% 
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~pal(ID_2),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight =2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE),
              label = ~paste0(NAME_2, ", ", NAME_1))
```

Hope this helps.